# Javascript cannot link with assets folder when hosted in github pages

Tags: github, github-pages

I made a website with Muse and decided to host it in a github pages.

I use howler.js for audio and put it in the js file.

When testing it locally, my website is working fine. my audio works fine. However, when I host it in github pages, the audio links broke and I get a 404 error

Here is my js file.

```
const underwater = new Howl({
  src: ["../assets/underwater.mp3", "Add File", "Add File"],
  autoplay: false,
  volume: 0.5,
  loop: true,
  preload: true,
  rate: 1
});
```

the code works fine locally.

But, when hosted in github pages, i see that the links becomes like this:
https://username.github.io/assets/underwater.mp3

It should be like this:
https://username.github.io/myproject/assets/underwater.mp3

Do you have any idea how to workaround this problem? Very appreciate for any help...

Thank you

Comment: This depends on your directory tree, but try using an absolute path (ex. `/assets/underwater.mp3` if `assets` is under the `_site` directory when rendered with Jekyll).

Answer (score 0):

I think you may replace parent call (../) by (./) on this way:

```
const underwater = new Howl({
  src: ["./assets/underwater.mp3", "Add File", "Add File"],
  autoplay: false,
  volume: 0.5,
  loop: true,
  preload: true,
  rate: 1
});
```

Check how I change ../assets by ./assets

Comment: Hi Julian, i tried that but still no luck. To clarify more, my javascript file is in a script folder, too, so I think it should use 
../assets/underwater.mp3 to access the source file...
But, please correct me if I'm wrong...